# How to call a python script from within an R script using data from the R dataframe and add result to new column

Tags: python, r

I would like to use a python program, which I can call in the command line, from within an R script and then call this program for every row in a data frame, add the result to the data frame and then export the data frame as .tsv data.

My example is this: I have a data frame where in column 2 there is a string (amino_acid) and I would like to call the program "olga-compute_pgen" on every string in column 2 and add the resulting numerical value from "olga-compute_pgen" to a new column in the data frame.

my command in the terminal (I use MacOS) would be

olga-compute_pgen --humanTRB (and here would be the string)

An example with output would be:

```
olga-compute_pgen --humanTRB CASSLGRDGGHEQYF
```

which leads to this output:

Pgen of the amino acid sequence CASSLGRDGGHEQYF: 7.253421763151433e-10

Completed pgen computation in: 0.05 seconds.

The line of code, where I want to add a column to my dataframe and fill it with the python results is right now

```
df <- cbind(df,NewColumn=(system('olga-compute_pgen --humanTRB') df[,2], wait=FALSE))
```

but this obviously does not work at all.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

***Edit:***

after some help, I have gotten some of it to work and I'll post the progress here, because the code is easier to read:

system2 seems to be a good start, because I can give a command with an argument and then output it into a dataframe to edit further:

I now have two problems left:

1. this line cannot use a value of a previous dataframe as additional input for the command, but rather uses strings

   olga <- system2('olga-compute_pgen' , args="--humanTRB ", input=x, wait=TRUE, stdout=TRUE)
2. The output (once I have gotten the input to work) should then be appended to the original data frame in a new column

Thanks for the help already!

***Edit2: Solution***

I have gotten this to work with a combination of "system2" and "foreach", here is what I did in the end:

```
#dataframe is df
#first define the function to use (in this case olga from python)
olgafunction <- function(y) {
    olga <- system2('olga-compute_pgen', args=c("--humanTRB ",
        as.character(y[,2])), wait=TRUE, stdout=TRUE)
    y <- cbind(y, pgen=olga)
    }
#now use this function for every row of the dataframe
dfoutput <- foreach(dfrow=iter(df, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %do%
    olgafunction(dfrow)
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the output from your external programme (python programme) into an R variable, for a single amino acid? This is your first hurdle. From what I can see of your single line of code, is that you haven't tried to make that part work. Revisit your code, and try to make it work for a single amino acid.

Comment: you're right, even this part does not work. If I use

`olgatest <- system('olga-compute_pgen --humanTRB CASSLGRDGGHEQYF', wait=FALSE)`

then my variable is a simple "0" and not the number I want.

Comment: You might be interested in [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/). Won't directly help you parse the command line output, but as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the late reply and harsh tone in the previous comment. I was trying to help you learn to debug your issues, which you successfully are now. `system` returns the *exit status* of the executable. You can read this from the documentation for the `system`-function (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html). All programmes returns an exit status (usually with 0 for successful termination), and this is quite different from what it *outputs* to the screen.

I would however advice you to take a look at the function `system2`, which should be a bit more sturdy and flexible. Take a look at the use of the `stdout` arguments, this would be key to solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now use system2 and a few things work. What I cannot get to work, however, is that my python command uses a value of a cell in my dataframe instead of a string and then outputs it into another cell.

`lapply(tsvdatei[,2], function(x) {

    olga <-system2('olga-compute_pgen' , args="--humanTRB ", input=x, wait=TRUE, stdout=TRUE)

    olga <- olga[2]

    olga <- gsub("Pgen of the amino acid sequence ", "", olga)

    olga <- gsub("[A-Z]","",olga)

    olga <- gsub(": ","",olga)

    olga <- as.numeric(olga)

    tsvdatei[,92] <- olga

  })`

Comment: The `input` argument is, if memory serves me right, passed as something typed in. You need to pass your value as a *command line argument*, just as you wrote in the original question. So you can use `system2('olga', args=c('--human', <<your value>>)`. Secondly, a cell in a data.frame *is* a string (or numeric), so you should easily be able to pass it the value as you do now.

Comment: I got it to work with your help, I'll post what I did in the original question, thanks a lot!